# Why does getRemoteAddr() return an ip address as a string?

Tags: java, servlets

Is there a reason that ServletRequest.getRemoteAddr() returns the clients ip address as a string instead of as an int/long/IPSomethingInstance?

Or asked an other way: Is there any case where the value returned by getRemoteAddr() can't be parsed as a numeric ip address?

Returning an ip address as a string, and then having the developer translate it to an ipV4/IpV6 address seems like a wrong design to me, unless there really is cases where the method returns something other then a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This method is there as a direct equivalent of the CGI variable `REMOTE_ADDR`, so I would guess that's the reason why it's string. And for what's the reason the CGI variable to be string - I don't know.

Comment: I guess that is the reason. I was just worried by the fact that the method might return a domain name or something weird instead of an   ip address. But I guess I can just assume that it is an ip address, and then add it to the list of design failures in java. (And there are methods to get server variables and cgi variables by name, so I guess the method really is redundant).

Answer (score 0):

Presumably to be consistent with `getRemoteHost()`, which can return an IP or a resolved name.

Comment: Is it sure that it will return the domain name if it has a resolved domain name?

Answer (score 0):

If a container returns something other than an IP from [ServletRequest.getRemoteAddr()](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getRemoteAddr%28%29), then it's not complying with the API:

```
"Returns the Internet Protocol (IP) address of the client
 or last proxy that sent the request."
```

I can only guess that it's done that way because the java.net classes can be a little odd.

Answer (score 0):

I do agree it would be convenient to return the address as an object which provides helpful methods for dealing with IP Addresses.

String works just fine though and is more flexible to changes in IP Address formats in the future (though that's speculative design, which probably isn't a great practice).

Comment: But if they ever did return something other then an ip address, they would silently break all code which expect an numeric ip address string.

Comment: Actually, if the API changed, the client code would not silently break - it would loudly break by not compiling. (e.g. if getRemoteHost() returned IpAddress instead of String)

Answer (score 0):

I would say, the IP can impossibly be numeric since the single parts of the IP are separated by dots and colons (IPv6). I suppose you're talking about Java. Unfortunately, I don't know much about Java, so I don't know if there is any `IPSomethingInstance`. But if it bothers you that much, why don't just write an own?

Also I assume that it's easier to pass over a string to functions and methods taking an IP as a parameter than an instance of a rather unnecessary native object.